# Ansible- find the servers which does not have a matching string in config file and display only the servers which does not have the string

Tags: ansible, formatting

am trying to get all the servers which does not have the correct ip address in the cfg file
and list only those servers in the out put. NO matter how i code it omits the hosts in the result and displays only the ones that has the string.

```
   - name: notmatch
       command: grep 'ip' /home/ansibleuser/pre-ifcfg 
       register: result'
   - debug:
        msg: result.stdout
     when: result is failed
     when: result.rc == 0
```

Comment: You are declaring `when` twice. The last declaration wins, which is `previous task was successfull`. Moreover, as is, you debug task will never play when your grep fails since the playbook will stop for the current host as soon as `result.rc != 0`. Please show an example of your `pre-ifcfg` file ans what you are trying to match exactly. You should not use shell for this. A good candidate would be the [`fetch` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html)

Comment: Hi there @user1747537, If you want the servers that doesn't have the string then I you might want to  use the "grep with -L" command. If you are just using the grep, then it will only give the results that contain the ip. So check on that. But not sure how your result variable shows that. Also check to modify your when condition with logical operators "and/or" --> tricky but think through.